# How to change the column names of a hashtable before it gets exported to Excel?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have a powershell function that reads a Sharepoint list and puts it into a hashtable and then export it to Excel. In the code the InternalName of all the Sharepoint list columns are specified:

```
$Global:selectProperties=@("Datum","Before","between","after","Opmerkingen");
```

But what I would like is when the Sharepoint list is read and the hashtable is created to change the column names of the hashtable before it gets exported to excel. is that possible?

This is the whole code:

```
function ExportList($listName)
{ 
    try 
    {  
        $listItems=(Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -Fields $Global:selectProperties).FieldValues 
        $outputFilePath="c:\Temp\" + $listName + ".xlsx"
        $hashTable=@()  
        foreach($listItem in $listItems) 
        { 
            $obj=New-Object PSObject             
            $listItem.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Key -in $Global:selectProperties } | 
                ForEach-Object {
                    if( $_.Key -eq 'Datum' )
                    {
                        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty $_.Key $_.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty $_.Key $_.Value
                    }
                } 
            $hashTable+=$obj; 
            $obj=$null; 
        } 
 
        $hashtable | Export-XLSX $outputFilePath -Table -Autofit -Force
     } 
     catch [Exception] 
     { 
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message        
        Write-Host "Error: $ErrorMessage" -ForegroundColor Red         
     } 
}
```

Thank you in advanced,

Greetings, P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add aliases to your PSObject.

For example, if you want to rename OLDName to NewName, you can use the following code:

```
$hashTable | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name NewName -Value OLDName -PassThru | Select-Object Title2
```

If you need to select multiple columns or aliases:

`... | Select-Object ColumnA, ColumnB, Alias2`

**Demo**

[image]

**Update**

Based on your comments, this is the code you want to use right before you export your array of custom objects to Excel:

```
$hashTable = $hashTable | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name "00:00" -Value Before -PassThru `
| Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name "06:30" -Value "between" -PassThru `
| Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name "14:30" -Value "after" -PassThru `
| Select-Object "Datum","00:00", "06:30",  "14:30","Opmerkingen"

$hashtable | Export-XLSX $outputFilePath -Table -Autofit -Force
```

Comment: I need to change the sharepoint list internal names: "Datum","Before","between","after","Opmerkingen"   to "Datum","00:00","06:30","14:30","Opmerkingen". Can you help because I don't understand your solution. Gr. P

Comment: Updated my answer. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.